# How to decide where to save `GenServer` data, `state` or `defstruct` or `Process.put`?

Tags: elixir

I want to save some data for pid of `GenServer`, and there are 3 option. One is for `GenServer`'s state. The second is save data through module `Process.put`. Both options exist in `erlang` language.

The third is module's `defstruct`, which doesn't exist in `erlang` language. Which consideration is behind the choice? Especially, between `defstruct` and `state`.

For example, in
[nx project](https://github.com/elixir-nx/nx),
The following `Nx.Defn.Stream` is from `Nx` project, `defstruct` include 3 element `:pid`, `:input`, `:output`.

Why not save `:input`, `:output` to `state`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `GenServer`’s state is a handy abstraction on top of `Process`’ dictionary (which `Process.put/1` deals with,) there is a huge difference between `struct` and process’ state.

Process’ state is a dynamic state, while the struct is just a static struct. Because everything in [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang)/[elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is immutable, one cannot “store” anything dynamic in the struct.

State of `Nx.Defn.Stream` is what is returned from `init/1` callback as by `GenServer` specification, namely [`{:queue.new(), :queue.new(), acc, fun}`](https://github.com/elixir-nx/nx/blob/main/nx/lib/nx/defn/stream.ex#L20). What is returned from `start_link/3` does not actually matter, because this function is not a part of any behaviour and not a callback.

That said, to keep a state of the process in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) one might use any erlang term (`Nx.Defn.Stream` uses a tuple of size 4, as shown above.) This state would be naturally passed through all `handle_call/3`, `handle_cast/2` and `handle_info/2` callbacks and might be modified in them, returning the new state as shown in the documentations to these functions.

---

*Sidenote:* `struct` is nothing but a bare [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) map underneath, having one additional field `__struct__` and some syntactic sugar, expanded by [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) compiler.